# How to extract a value from a received REST API array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest

I've been stuck on this for 8 hours so I am finally posting for help:

I am trying to extract data from a REST API response in my javascript file. The REST API data returns an array of objects like so:

```
[{"start":"2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire":"no","address":"The 
Monument","offer_id":"z554"},
{"start":"2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire":"no","address":"The 
Gate","offer_id":"z123"},
{"start":"2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire":"yes","address":"The 
Port","offer_id":"z999"}] }
```

I need to extract the address value from each element so that I can pass it as an argument to another function called updateAddressBook().

From what I understand the response data is in JSON format, so I will have to parse it into a javascript object, then iterate over the array and pull out the address info.

```
$.get('http://xxxx/,
          function (data) {
              var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
              $.each(obj.data, function (index, value) {
                      updateAddressBook(address)
                          }
                     });
```

This code is clearly wrong but hopefully someone can tell me where I am going wrong!

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: The JSON you entered here is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If the data your API is sending is already in JSON format, then you do not need to convert it to an object when you get the response, jquery does that for you. Additionally you need to get the address property from the iterated object: **value.address**. The code should look like this

```
$.get('http://xxxx/',
    function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (index, value) {
           updateAddressBook(value.address)
       }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately, not sure why.
I tried putting an alert("test"); within the loop but it wouldn't execute. If I place the alert statement right above the $.each line, I see the alert appear

Comment: What does it say if you do alert(data) above the loop?

Comment: managed to get it fixed, but have another problem!
value.address seems to be undefined.
If I do: address = value.address; alert(address); it pops up as undefined, and no addresses are being passed to the other function. Any idea why that would be !?

Comment: console.log(value) and see what it says

Comment: ugh sorry the mistake was on my part, everything works perfect now. thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Also, after the JSON is correct, try this:

```
   $.getJSON('http://xxxx/', function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                     updateAddressBook(value.address);
                });
     });
```

Your JSON has an extra } at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Your `JSON` is not a valid `JSON`.

  [image]
- It should be structured like this.

  [image]
- If response is a `JSON Object` then no need to parse it again. You can directly access the address by iterating the JSON using `loop`.

  **DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00",
  "hire": "no",
  "address": "address1",
  "Monument": "monument1",
  "offer_id": "z554"
 },
 {
  "start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00",
  "hire": "no",
  "address": "address2",
  "Gate": "gate2",
  "offer_id": "z123"
 }, {
  "start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00",
  "hire": "yes",
  "address": "address3",
  "Port": 8082,
  "offer_id": "z999"
 }
];

for (var i in jsonObj) {
    updateAddressBook(jsonObj[i].address);
}

function updateAddressBook(address) {
  console.log(address);
}
```

- If response is a `JSON String` then first parse it and then iterate.

  **DEMO**

```js
var jsonStr = '[{"start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire": "no","address": "address1","Monument": "monument1","offer_id": "z554"},{"start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire": "no","address": "address2","Gate": "gate2","offer_id": "z123"},{"start": "2017-04-21 14:40:00","hire": "yes","address": "address3","Port": 8082,"offer_id": "z999"}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for (var i in jsonObj) {
    updateAddressBook(jsonObj[i].address);
}

function updateAddressBook(address) {
  console.log(address);
}
```